# TickLabelSpacing for months

Tags: vba, graph, axis, spacing

So I have a graph which has months on the x-axis. Currently VBA automatically steps through these months in steps of two. So, on the x-axis I see (for example): May-15, July-15, Sept-15, Nov-15... and so on. I want to see, May-15, Jun-15, July-15, Aug-15, Sept-15, Oct-15, Nov-15,...ie I want to change the x-axis to steps of one month. I have tried:

```
      Charts("Chart 3").Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelSpacing = 1
```

But receive subscript out of range error?!
Please, any tips? Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the x-axis units displayd on the chart you need to change `Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit` or `Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit`

Try (this is an approximate of 1 month = 30 days):

```
' you can modify ActiveSheet and set a variable with your Worksheet name 
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 30
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I still get the same error? Though I think your on the right line...will have a play

Comment: @MrNemo try the modifed code, you need to select the active chart in order to modify it's properties

Comment: Cheers. Got there in the end